# No posts are being listed by <plugin-list-category-post>

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I just installed the List Category Post plugin, and I've followed the directions. No posts are being listed. For example, at the end of this page, there should be a list, and it's just blank.

Is the plugin working on 3.1?

Answer (score 1):

Oops. It turns out that the posts in the category I wanted were scheduled for the future, which means they were hidden from the code. Nevermind!

Comment: You should mark your answer as correct in case others go through a similar problem. Thanks for using the plugin!